# Chrome not displaying divs

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This works fine on Firefox and IE but 3 divs on the right are missing on Chrome. Any suggestions would be great. It's weird that some of the divs (7,8,9) are not rendered on Chrome. Could this be a Chrome bug?

Is there no one out there who can answer this?

http://jsfiddle.net/2LfLtem6/

Css and HTML

```
<style type="text/css">
.ma_content {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-top:-40px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 0;
    width:800px;
}
.u_content {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
}
.u_content img:hover {      
    opacity: .8;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9,0.9);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9,0.9);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.top_kutucuk {
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
}

.bottom_kutucuk {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
}

.left_kutucuk {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.right_kutucuk {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}

.center_kutucuk {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}

.kutucuk_1 {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.kutucuk_2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.kutucuk_3 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.kutucuk_4 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.kutucuk_5 {
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.kutucuk_6 {
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.kutucuk_7 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.kutucuk_8 {
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.kutucuk_9 {
    height: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.kutucuk_10 {
    width: 800px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>

<div class="ma_content">
        <div class="top_kutucuk kutucuk_1">
            <div class="u_content"><a href="#" title="" target="_self"><img src="Image4.png" width="198" height="396"></a>
                <div class="left_kutucuk kutucuk_3">
                    <div class="u_content">
                        <div class="top_kutucuk kutucuk_4">
                            <div class="u_content"><a href="#" title="" target="_self"><img src="Image1.png" width="297" height="148"></a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="left_kutucuk kutucuk_5">
                            <div class="u_content"><a href="#" title="" target="_self"><img src="Image2.png" width="148" height="248"></a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right_kutucuk kutucuk_6">
                            <div class="u_content"><a href="#" title="" target="_self"><img src="Image3.png" width="148" height="248"></a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right_kutucuk kutucuk_2">
                    <div class="u_content">
                        <div class="left_kutucuk kutucuk_8">
                            <div class="u_content"><a href="#" title="" target="_self"><img src="Image5.png" width="148" height="248"></a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right_kutucuk kutucuk_9">
                            <div class="u_content"><a href="#" title="" target="_self"><img src="Image6.png" width="148" height="248"></a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bottom_kutucuk kutucuk_7">
                            <div class="u_content"><a href="#" title="" target="_self"><img src="Image7.png" width="297" height="148"></a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="top_kutucuk kutucuk_10">
            <div class="u_content"><a href="#" title="" target="_self"><img src="Image8.png" width="797" height="148"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So we have to find out which divs, or are you willing to tell?

Comment: Divs are 8, 9 and 7.

Comment: It seems div 2 is pushed down and is behind div 10. Can't really tell why, but in case someone wants to experiment some more: http://jsfiddle.net/2LfLtem6/ To me this is far from [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: GolezTrol thanks for the jsfiddle link. This is my first post on stackoverflow. Could take out the image and hover bits. But thought that the example code was minimal as it is.

Comment: I would have used a table and some rowspan/colspan to achieve that, what you've created.. just wow!

Comment: Thanks Brunis. Any ideas why Chrome is not displaying these divs?

Comment: remove `overflow: hidden;` from `.kutucuk_1` and you will see your divs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle HTML begins with:

```
<div class="ma_content">
        <div class="top_kutucuk kutucuk_1">
            <div class="u_content"><a href="#" title="" target="_self"><img src="Image4.png" width="198" height="396"></a>
```

add `float: left` to anchor and move it between those two divs on the same DOM level: http://jsfiddle.net/2LfLtem6/4/

**Short explanation: if you mix floated block divs with inline content then you'll have a very big headache and messed up layout :)**

Comment: The middle section is now on the left hand side. The layout is not the way it should be. 200x400 should be centered. Please check out original version.

Comment: what can I say. You have to choose: float or inline. This two lovers doesn't cooperate very well :) Otherwise you will loose countless hours to figure this out, not to mention your sanity :) But if you want to preserve some order just change it in html: http://jsfiddle.net/2LfLtem6/4/

Comment: The last version does the trick. All in the name of sanity :) Thanks.

Comment: No problem Tom :) Please mark answer if it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look at your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/2LfLtem6/)
Divs 8,9 and 7 are indeed not visible when you open the link - but they are visible via chrome inspector.

After tweaking the css a little I found that you should increase the `.kutucuk_1` height to fit all the divs in it.  Like this:

```
.kutucuk_1 {
 width: 800px;
 height: 800px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/2LfLtem6/2/

Tweak it any way u want

Comment: Chrome still rendering messed up.